# Failed to start Network Time Synchronisation

Tags: linux, boot, debian

When I turned on my desktop running Linux Debian I got a error message that says:

```
[Failed] Failed to start Network Time Synchronisation
```

This is what I see: https://ibb.co/SVnsfmK

How do I go about resolving this please?

Answer (score 1):

Fixed via:

- Selected advanced options in GRUB menu
- Selected recovery console
- Ran blkid --> https://ibb.co/BgFHpvN
- umounted correct partition
- ran fsck /dev/sdc3
- ran sudo update-grub
- reboot

And now everything works like before :-)